# Failed on Start (Workflow was canceled by System Account.)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, debugging, conditional

When I add an "**if condition**" to my working workflow, It doesn't work anymore and gives error: "Failed to Start". (Workflow was canceled by System Account.)

My "**if condition**" is in below image framed by blue, when I add blue section, workflow doesn't start. Can you help please ?

[image]

Comment: Try to Log in and start the workflow as a different user (rather than System Account) to test & check if it is working for you or not.

Comment: @Hardik Someone else tried to start the workflow, it did not work. The error is same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your issue, I recommend to follow the steps as below:

1. Clear SharePoint Designer cache: [How to Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/)
2. Deactivate all "Workflow" features at the Site Collection level.
3. Enable all "Workflow" features at the Site Collection level.
4. PSCONFIG (Not Necessary) (or run the SharePoint 2010 products configuration wizard)
5. Delete the bad workflow.
6. Create a new workflow on the list with an valid user.

Comment: Did you tried above steps? Is that works for you?

Comment: Just step 1 resolved it, there was no need for other steps!

Comment: Same issue here, just step 1 was enough :) Again weird behaviour of SP....

Answer (score 3):

In case it might be helpful for someone:

I had a similar problem with a client today in a SP 2013 environment, but in my case turned out that it was a .Net security update that caused it.

The solution after this update was to add some types to the web.config file on the SharePoint server:

```
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeBinaryOperatorExpression" Authorized="True" />
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodePrimitiveExpression" Authorized="True" />
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeMethodInvokeExpression" Authorized="True" />
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeMethodReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeFieldReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeThisReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodePropertyReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />
```

Here's the Microsoft article for reference:

[SharePoint workflows stop working after you install .NET security updates for CVE-2018-8421](https://support.microsoft.com/nb-no/help/4465015/sharepoint-workflows-stop-after-cve-2018-8421-security-update)