# Workflow Cancelled with no Error Received

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I have started a workflow and it is getting cancelled with no error received:

[image]

No errors are shown:

[image]

What would be the cause of this?

I am using SharePoint 2013 Standard, and the workflow is a custom workflow created by SharePoint Designer.

This is not happening on all instances of the workflow.

Comment: due to it happens not on all instances I would firstly look at SP Cache like in this post: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185571/failed-on-start-workflow-was-canceled-by-system-account

Comment: Not related, the workflow sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't. It is not an SPD issue. It is a workflow issue. Multiple users instantiate the workflow, since a new request for Vacation Leave triggers it.